# Display multi-index columns as merged cells when printing a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

Context: I'm using streamlit to display a dataframe on a small web-app and I have a multi-index column. Let's say we have this dataframe:

```
arrays = [
    ["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
    ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"],
]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=[None, "Brand"])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns=index)
df
```

Printing the dataframe on python it displays this:

[image]

Which is the wanted results.

However, when I display the same dataframe using streamlit `st.dataframe(df)` it looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it so that the multi-index columns on the first level are not repeated? I essentially would like them to be merged in a single cell in streamlit

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a pandas [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide) to hide the unwanted index labels.

I used a Styler to colorize labels, and in Streamlit I use the st.table() object to display it, but dataframe works as well (I simply thought table was more attractive colorized).

Here's an example:

```py
def colorize_session(df):

    team_list = df.copy()

    def highlight_redbull(s, props=""):
        return np.where(s == "Red Bull Racing", props, "")

    team_list = team_list.style

    team_list = team_list.apply(
        highlight_redbull,
        props='font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;font-size:13px;color:#1e5bc6',
        axis=0)

    return team_list

with st.spinner("Loading session data..."):
    try:
        fig, picked_event_df = get_session_results()
        df = colorize_session(picked_event_df)
        st.table(df)
    except ValueError:
        st.text("Select a session...")
```

Using a similar styler, you can set the opacity of the text to 0 from the CSS `color:` key-value you pass in `props`.